# Get values of edittext in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I want get values of edittext in listview.
This is my CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
List<RowItem> rowItem;

ImageView imgIcon, add_cart;
TextView txtTitle;

EditText colli, prezzo, quantita;
String colliStr, prezzoStr, quantitaStr;

ArrayList<String> ArrayPrezzo = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> ArrayQuantita = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> ArrayColli = new ArrayList<String>();

CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> rowItem) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItem = rowItem;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return rowItem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return rowItem.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return rowItem.indexOf(getItem(position));
}
@Override
public boolean  areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null);
    }

    imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    add_cart = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    colli = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    prezzo = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    quantita = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);

    add_cart.setFocusable(true);
    add_cart.setClickable(true);

    final RowItem row_pos = rowItem.get(position);
    // setting the image resource and title
    imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.product);
    txtTitle.setText(row_pos.getTitle());

    add_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // HERE I WANT GET THE VALUES OF EDITTEXT;

        }
    });

        return convertView;
}
```

can someone help me please? In ly listview there are:
textview | edittext1 | edittext2 | edittext3 | imageview
I don't know how to get values of edittext at position current when i click the button.
Can you make a example with my code?
Thnank you

UPDATE:
I have edited the listener:

```
add_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            prezzoStr = prezzo.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, prezzoStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }
    });
```

but prezzoStr is empty. Toast doesn't show nothing.
I think need use row_pos variable for getting the value of a determinate edittext.
Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get parent view and then find text view by id:

```
 add_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView prezzo = (TextView) findByIdRecursively(v, R.id.editText2);
               String prezzoStr = prezzo.getText().toString();
            }
        });
```

...

```
public View findByIdRecursively(View view, int targetId) {
    View result = view.findViewById(targetId);
    if (result != null) {
        return result;
    }
    View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    if (parent == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return findByIdRecursively(parent, targetId);
}
```

The view in onClick is the view that was clicked (add_cart in this case)

... or you can do:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

...

    add_cart = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    add_cart.setTag(convertView);

    add_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView prezzo = (TextView) ((View)v.getTag()).findViewById(R.id.editText2);
               String prezzoStr = prezzo.getText().toString();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi, my app crash with : java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewRootImpl cannot be cast to android.view.View - here:         View parent = (View) view.getParent(); and here:         return findParentRecursively(parent, targetId);

Comment: In OnClick event i have: prezzo = (EditText) findParentRecursively(v, R.id.editText2);
                String prezzoStr = prezzo.getText().toString();

Comment: I've updated the answer. My initial solution was wrong.

Comment: You are number one! it work! ...but what is the scope of setTag?

Answer (score 2):

It's not difficult

```
add_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          String colliValue = colli.getText().toString());
          String prezzoValue = prezzo.getText().toString());
          String quantitaValue = quantita.getText().toString());
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but doesn't work for me. I have updated 1st post.. help please!